# Is using possessive pronouns after a name to show possession instead of apostrophe grammatical, like “John his car” for “John’s car”?

Tags: apostrophe, saxon-genitive, possessive-pronouns, hypercorrection

I've sometimes seen people use this so I was wondering if it is actually correct grammar or not. Couldn't find anything saying that this is correct nor anything saying that this is wrong online.

What I'm talking about is people saying e.g. "John his car" or "Apple their product designer" instead of "John's car" or "Apple's product designer".

Does anyone know if this is grammatically correct or not and could maybe even link some sources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This prac­tice, which is some­times known as the [***his
genitive***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/His_genitive), is not
con­sid­ered gram­mat­i­cal in present-day English.

The Wikipedia sum­mary is:

> The **his gen­i­tive** is a means of form­ing a gen­i­tive con­struc­tion by
> link­ing two nouns with a pos­ses­sive pro­noun such as “his” (e.g. “my
> friend his car” in­stead of “my friend’s car”). This con­struc­tion
> en­joyed only a brief hey­day in English in the late 16th cen­tury and
> the 17th cen­tury, but is com­mon in some of the di­alects of a num­ber of
> Ger­manic lan­guages, and stan­dard in Afrikaans.

If you read their ar­ti­cle and fol­low through to the pri­mary
sources, you will see that this for­mu­la­tion never oc­curred in
Old English, and that dur­ing a brief pe­riod it oc­curred as
mis­taken hy­per­cor­rec­tion. It was all a big mis­take.

Comment: I always assumed that ***John his house** burned down* was the "original" for modern-day possessive ***John's house** burned down*. But I'm perfectly happy to stand corrected on that point.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, that's the common folk etymology, but it is a myth.

Comment: The Old English nominative for house was hus (strong neuter), and for dog (strong masculine), hund. In the genitive these became "huses"  and hundes. There were other genitive suffixes for feminine and a limited number of other nouns but they did not withstand the test of time. The apostrophe thus indicates the missing "e".